# Inorganic chemistry handbook with reaction lists

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reference-request, books

There is a handy handbook on common inorganic substances' properties called "Reactivity of Inorganic Substances" (eds. R. A. Lidin, V. A. Molochko, and L. L. Andreeva). It was originally written in Russian and then translated into English (see the review [here](https://doi.org/10.1021/je960367c)). The entries in this handbook go like this (sorry for the Russian, couldn't find the English version):

[image]

You see that the compound's name is followed by the brief summary of its physical properties (color, solubility in water), general notes on its stability under ambient atmosphere, and then the list of the chemical reactions which were considered by the authors to be the most important or illustrative for this particular substance.

The question is - are there any reputable handbooks that are similar to this one, with not only the summary of the physical properties, but the summary of possible chemical reactions as well, or is this book one-of-a-kind?

Comment: There was much good chemistry written in other languages than English, and to some extent still is.  Skipping sources in Russian were like omitting important ressources, and not only from Russia itself.

Comment: In the 1970s, learning Russian/German was one of the requirements to do a PhD in chemistry. If one had to become an electrochemist, Russian was highly recommended. Still many top universities in USA require a foreign language exam for a PhD in mathematics. It is sad that most of the scientists don't bother to learn other languages now.

Comment: There is Holleman-Wiberg, an originally German (the very first edition was actually dutch, in 1898) compendium of biblical size, including a ~5-20 page chapter on every main group and side group element, with properties and reactions for most all simple inorganic compounds. And of course the CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics.

Comment: Indeed Holleman Wiberg is another giant contribution. It was quite recently translated into English. Most of the people are also not aware of Mellor's Treatise on Inorganic Chemistry from 1920-30s. It is at least 9-10 volumes by a single author- element by element. One of the best ever.

Comment: @M.Farooq They translated it again? There was an English edition already in the first quarter of the last century. I love these books which, to avoid making them in two or even three volumes, are printed on this very fine, thin paper, like telephone books, or bibles.

Comment: I meant 2001. I have seen it in the library. However I was not aware of the early Holleman's translation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An Intro in Russian edition of *Reactivity of Inorganic Substances* by Lidin et al. claims its uniqueness:

> Настоящее пособие носит информационно-справочный характер, не имеет аналогов в отечественной и зарубежной химической литературе, охватывает все разделы неорганической химии, изучаемые в химических вузах.
>
> (English) This reference handbook has no analogues among domestic and foreign chemical literature, covers all inorganic chemistry sections studied in university chemistry course.

However, Turova's *Inorganic Chemistry in Tables* comes pretty close.
It doesn't only list reactions per element groups, but also arranges them in visual blocks; available both in Russian and English [1, 2]:

[image: Turova]

#### References

1. Турова, Н. Я. Неорганическая Химия в Таблицах; *Высший химический колледж РАН: Москва*, **1997**.
2. Turova, N. Inorganic Chemistry in Tables; *Springer: Heidelberg ; New York*, **2011**. ISBN 978-3-642-20486-9.

Answer (score 6):

I am not aware of a list like this however, the biggest database on Earth of inorganic materials/reactions is the *Gmelin Handbuch der Anorganische Chemie*. Obviously in German since late 1770s and specific to element by element. The later editions started in English since 1970s. It is descriptive unlike the reference you have mentioned. Reaxys (Elsevier) has taken over Gmelin Handbuch and its organic counter part Beilstein. All in English.